# admob ads no longer work

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I haven't updated my app in a few months and when I tried to admob ads dont load. This is what the logcat shows:

```
12-12 16:12:54.975: INFO/Ads(23032): Request scenario: Online server request.
    12-12 16:12:55.526: ERROR/Ads(23032): AdLoader can't parse gWhirl server configuration.
12-12 16:12:55.526: INFO/Ads(23032): The following was caught and handled:
    org.json.JSONException: No value for ad_networks
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:544)
    at com.google.ads.c.a(SourceFile:102)
    at com.google.ads.internal.c.b(SourceFile:994)
    at com.google.ads.internal.c.run(SourceFile:902)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
12-12 16:12:55.526: INFO/Ads(23032): onFailedToReceiveAd(There was an internal error.)
```

what could cause this to happen?

Comment: If you are using AdWhirl, they turned it off: http://techcrunch.com/2013/06/13/google-shuts-down-mobile-ad-aggregator-adwhirl-asks-developers-to-use-admob-mediation-instead/

Comment: I have never heard of adwhirl, is it possible I could have previously been using it without knowing?

Comment: I'm only guessing based on your logcat. 'gWhirl' made me think that AdWhirl was setup. You would have to investigate if you ended up using that service or not.

Comment: I only set up the admob sdk I didn't do anything else. Has anything major changed since August in the sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Many things have changed with Admob in the last month or so.

One of the main changes is the move to distributing the Admob SDK via the Google Play Services library  and the change of package and some change of interfaces that occurred with that. Suggest you look at https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals

The other is the move to the new Admob dashboard and with that the change in the AdUnitId that you should provide with your ad. It now looks something like 'ca-pub-XXXXXXXXX-YYYYYYYY"

But having said that, I still have apps that have yet to make the change and they continue to run just fine. If you were already using Google Play Services and upgraded that then you might be in a weird state. If that's the case then I strongly suggest you roll Admob forward to use the GPS classes too.